# Automatically launch an app and click a button in it

Tags: java, android, ios, flutter, react-native

I want to automatically launch an application and click a button in it through another application like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codefish.sqedit&hl=en&gl=US).

I know it is some Accessibility settings needed to be enables for that app. But I don't know how to code it. I would appreciate the help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Suppose Your Application is `App1` and another application which is `App2` which is installed on your phone.

Do you want to lunch an application `App2` from the `App1`'s Button  Right ??.

Comment: App1 should launch App2 and click a button in App2

Answer (score 0):

Icant understand exactly whats your goal but if i understood, Maybe you're  looking  for deeplinking

Flutter supports deep linking on iOS, Android, and web browsers. Opening a URL displays that screen in your app.
See the documentation here

[Deep linking](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking)